# Resetting counter of number of times function can run

Tags: jquery

I have a function that I use in long polling. To limit the number of times it runs I use a counter:

```
var cnt = 0;

function poll() {

      if ($cnt < 10) {

           $.ajax({
            ...
            },
            dataType : 'json',
            async: true,
            success: function (response) {
            ...
            },
            complete: function() {
                 setTimeout(poll, 30000);
                 cnt = cnt + 1;
             }
         });
      }
}

poll() ;
```

I call the function on page load and sometimes on click. Is there a way to reset the counter to 0 when I call it on click?

```
$(document).on('click', '.myEm', function() {
    ...
    poll();
});
```

Comment: Can't you just set cnt to zero prior to calling poll()?

Comment: It is set to 0 when I call it on page load, after that it will call itself 10 times, however if I can it on click I need to reset it for another 10 runs, even if it already ran a few times after the page loaded.

Comment: Right, so in your click handler reset it to zero.

Comment: I tried. But the script continues with the earlier countdown...